# inline border-radius property does not apply inside generated email

Tags: html, css, outlook

I pass the HTML markup into the SmtpClient object and send it:

```
 using (SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient(Settings.SmtpServer))
                    {
                        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
                        {                               
                            message.From = new MailAddress(Settings.EmailFromAddressUS);                              

                            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(orderInfo.ShippingInfo.Email, string.Format("{0} {1}", orderInfo.ShippingInfo.FirstName, orderInfo.ShippingInfo.LastName)));
                            message.Subject = subjectLine;
                            message.Body = emailBody;
                            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                            SMTP.Send(message); 
                        }
                    }
```

Inside emailBody variable I have such mark up:

```
<a href="www.test.com" style="background-color: transparent;Margin:0;border:0 solid #46323c;border-radius:4px!important;border-collapse: separate;perspective: 1px; color:#46323c;display:inline-block;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;text-align:left;">Sign Up</a>
```

On the client's side (Outlook 2016) that's the html received:

```
<a href="www.test.com" style="border-radius:4px!important;perspective: 1px;display:inline-block"><b><span style="color:#46323C;border:solid #46323C 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:
          solid #46323C .25pt;padding:6.0pt;text-underline:none">Sign Up </span></b></a>
```

The `border-radius` property is not applied and the button is squared. If I save the email as html I will have a rounded button as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

if it is outlook, it may not be passed, the following pass:-

border-left

border-right

border-top

border-bottom

border-left-color

border-left-width

border-left-style

border-right-color

border-right-width

border-right-style

border-top-color

border-top-width

border-top-style

border-bottom-color

border-bottom-width

border-bottom-style

border-radius is at the helms mercy of outlook, can you please confirm which client you need to pass? border-radius will not work on specific outlook versions, particularly when it comes to litmus version testing.

Comment: Client is outlook 2016, and it was tested using litmus

Comment: this would explain why, outlook 2016 does not support, I have not come across anything in outlook (in versions) that can use border-radius. I would perhaps try to use background png to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius` does not work with Outlook desktop clients.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/border-radius/

`border` is hit and miss with Outlook.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/border/

Your button is never going to look rounded using css. In email development, you do the best you can do and strive for graceful degradation of the features you want to include.

For more information on what does not work with Outlook or other email clients, Campaign Monitor has a fantastic reference.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

Good luck.